# Why is alert not popping up?

Tags: java, selenium, testing, automation, alert

I tried to put this in code.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='adduser']/div/form/div[2]/div/div/label")).click();
Thread.sleep(1000);

Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
String alertMessage = driver.switchTo().alert().getText();
System.out.println(alertMessage);
alert.accept();
```

I found the error message like "no alert is present".

Complete Java code is below..

```
package AddUser;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.NoAlertPresentException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class CheckFirstname
{
    public static WebDriver d;

    public static void main(String []args)throws Exception{
       System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette", "pathToGeckodriver");
       FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

       driver.get("http://54.68.159.204/qmsadm");
       driver.manage().window().maximize();
       WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("username"));
       element.sendKeys("user name");
       element = driver.findElement(By.name("password"));
       element.sendKeys("password");
       element.submit();
       element = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Admin"));
       element.click();
       element = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Users"));
       element.click();
       element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='search-container']/a/i"));
       element.click();

       element = driver.findElement(By.id("username"));
       element.sendKeys("#!#!#$@#!$@!$@#$%#%^#$^^&%&$%*");

       driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='adduser']/div/form/div[2]/div/div/label")).click();
       Thread.sleep(1000);

       WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 0);

       wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());

       Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();

       alert.accept();
   }
```

}

[image: Check this screen shot]

This is screenshot of screen. Here you can check an alert box. I want to pop up this alert window. I tried several times, but it's not working yet.

Comment: Then you need check first it's JavaScript alert or html

Comment: i@saurabh it's a javascript alert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like this:

**Before you try to switch to the alert, it needs to be present.**

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='adduser']/div/form/div[2]/div/div/label")).click(); Thread.sleep(1000);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());

Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
alertText = alert.getText();
alert.accept();
```

and why you are getting alert here `Alert alert=driver.switchTo().alert();` if you are not using in the below line `String alertMessage=driver.switchTo().alert().getText();`, you are just writing it unnecessary. Hope it helps.
complete java code is below.

```
package AddUser;



import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.NoAlertPresentException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

    public class CheckFirstname 
    {
    public static WebDriver d;
        public static void main(String []args)throws Exception{
           System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette","pathToGeckodriver");
           FirefoxDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();


           driver.get("http://54.68.159.204/qmsadm");
           driver.manage().window().maximize();
           WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.name("username"));
           element.sendKeys("geosony");
           element=driver.findElement(By.name("password"));
           element.sendKeys("1");
           element.submit();
           element=driver.findElement(By.linkText("Admin"));
           element.click();
           element=driver.findElement(By.linkText("Users"));
           element.click();
           element=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='search-container']/a/i"));
           element.click();




           element= driver.findElement(By.id("username"));
           element.sendKeys("#!#!#$@#!$@!$@#$%#%^#$^^&%&$%*");

           driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='adduser']/div/form/div[2]/div/div/label")).click();
           Thread.sleep(1000);

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30 );

            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());

        Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();

        alert.accept();






        }   
    }
```

Comment: i found  this error    Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for alert to be present (tried for 0 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)

Comment: can you post complete code where you are creating webdriver object...surely there's some issue with that...

Comment: Here,  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 0 ); you have given wait time 0 just give some time man maybe 20, 30.  You error clearly states tried for 0 second(s)

Comment: i tried to put 30. i found the error   Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for alert to be present (tried for 30 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)

Comment: i got it thanks for the reponse . actually the probelem is that the alert box is not a javascript alert. its a html alert. i'm  losing  so many time.